# Accessing global C variable from java

Tags: java, c, multithreading, native

I'm calling a C function that resides in a dll from a java thread. This C function runs indefinitely and processes video frames in real time, outputting a result for each frame.

I want to spawn another java thread to read the results from the processing function without interrupting the function. I also need to implement some kind of thread control to protect from reading corrupted data.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you currently invoking the C function?

Comment: well I haven't yet implemented it, I have the C function ready and intend to call it using JNI

Comment: Are you on windows? Because "global" variables from a DLL point of view are rarely actually global. Sometimes they're global for everyone, but usually they're restricted to per-process or even per-thread.

Comment: I'm on windows, I have the C program ready. Want to transform it into DLL and then call it from java and use another java thread to access results. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Yes, I understand your goal, but what I'm saying is that it depends on how you're planning on calling it. If Java loads the DLL, starts the processor, and then repetitively checks on it, I'd just make another C function called "check_my_global" which returns the value. If on the other hand you're starting up a *new* java process, well then things get complicated.

Answer (score 1):

The global is controlled by your C environment.

I suspect that you should do this:

1. Create a function that returns the value of the global variable and call it from java using JNI.
2. Implement your synchronization stuff in C.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed your C function in a executable that will be started by your java thread. The C function can post results into a pipe or send them through a socket to your java thread. This gives you the flexibility to even have your C function running on one machine and the java thread on another.